# Make angular ui-bootstrap datepicker the only way to add date to input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to disable key input and force the user to use the datepicker to add date to the input but I don't know how to do this. 
In the current solution the user can select date but also type or erase the value directly in the input. I would like to disable the input, so the user can't type or erase anything, but still make the datepicker available.

Does angular ui-bootstrap already include this feature (checked the docs but didn't find any..) or do anyone have a solution for this?

This is a simpler version copy from the [ui-bootstrap docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but its basically what I use in my site:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy'
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
   
    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a readonly attribute to the input and it will work as you expect :)

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy'
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
   
    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text"readonly class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So simple and so great! How could I've missed that..Thanks!